# Contact Form 7 API plugin

Tags: wordpress, api, forms, plugin

Trying to do a contact form in WordPress, and failing on tiny little things.  A Profile using the Notes field sends an e-mail that always attaches only the first Note on a record.  Creating a custom field, the field gets overwritten every time a new form is filled out by the contact.  The Contact Form 7 API plugin seems promising as I can get it to e-mail everyone, including a CiviCRM processing account, and include it as a note.  However, then I can't get it to update/fill in other fields on the contact record.  Documentation is a little weak, as it was a custom created plugin for a specific purpose and then released with the hopes that somebody would find it useful and take off with it.  Has anyone got it working to "create or update" a contact and add an activity?  The API call seems to point only towards doing one thing from a form and not being able to handle an either/or situation.

CiviCRM 4.7, Wordpress

Comment: Yes, we did with the Contact Form 7 API (which we created for a specific customer as you mentioned :-))

Comment: @ErikH thanks to you and CiviCoop for sharing this integration, off-topic:  just wanted to add as an alternative the Caldera Forms CiviCRM integration https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm (it has a different purpose, ie is not meant to send data to another server/site, so if that's the intention then ignore this G H) it supports the entities mentioned among others, create/update Contacts, create Activities and also checksum support.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks!  Unfortunately, I was hoping to cross site this one.  Bouncing isn't out of the question though, so I'll definitely keep it in mind.  Here's to hoping that a tie-in to the API is on the road map, or an exporter like the Profile piece has.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we did with the Contact Form 7 API (which we created for a specific customer as you mentioned :-))

The Contact Form 7 API submits the form data with an API WpCivi Submit with a form type which links to the class that is called in CiviCRM. You can find the CiviCRM part of the customer extension we created [here](https://github.com/CiviCooP/be.werkmetzin.wpcivi), hope that helps you on your way!

Comment: thanks for the pointer.  I had been there.  My pea brain is missing something though.  Is this extension a Civi Extension that goes beyond the WP plugins?  So, I need the Contact Form 7 Plugin, the CF7-Civi Plugin, and this extension?  I'll see what I can break on the dev machine.

Comment: Rats.  Getting an error on install.  Says it can't find a directory that is there.  Put it on the Github page.